# How can I get the HTML output from pycurl when there's a 500 error?

Tags: python, pycurl

I am trying to interact with a server using pycurl, and I'm getting a 500 error. I'd like to be able to see the text of the error coming back from the server, but pycurl doesn't seem to give me a way to do this.

For example, when I point 'curl' at the server, I get something like this:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -k -d @subcase.xml -X POST https://192.168.1.110/vision.asmx
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <detail>
        <ExceptionMessage>Invalid Case Objid -1 or idNumber 76029744 or Case is closed.</ExceptionMessage>
      </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But when I try to build out some pycurl that does the same thing, the HTML coming back from the server seems to get swallowed:

```
class Storage:
    '''An object used to hold the output of a pyCurl command'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = []
    def store(self, buf):
        self.contents.append(buf)
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(self.contents)

def go_get_it(url):
    curl_obj = pycurl.Curl()
    curl_obj.setopt(pycurl.URL, str(url))

    output = Storage()
    header = Storage()
    curl_obj.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, output.store)
    curl_obj.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, header.store)

    response = Response(header, output)
    if self.debug_level:
        curl_obj.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
        curl_obj.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, self.curl_debug)
    try:
        curl_obj.perform()
        status_code = curl_obj.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
        response.set_status_code(status_code)
        return response
    except pycurl.error, curl_err:
        print curl_obj.errstr()
```

If the server does not throw a 500 error, then the `output` object contains the HTML response from the server. However, when we get the exception, the output object is empty.
The HTML coming back from the server is also not available in `curl_err` (as far as I can tell).

Does anyone know if there's a way to recover the HTML coming back from the server in this situation?

Comment: You are looking for Python Requests library http://docs.python-requests.org/ ;)

Comment: Wow. I tried out python-requests and I can't believe how easy it is. I'm a long-time pycurl user, but I'm never going back. Thanks!